# Inner Join on Update

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to figure out how to get this to work.

```
    UPDATE 
systems AS C 
SET C.nulled = '1' 
FROM systems 
INNER JOIN systems AS P 
ON C.nullif = P.sid 
WHERE P.status = 1
```

I'm not 100% if i'm doing this correctly. I want to update C.null to 1 if the P.sid equals the nullif column in C.

Comment: `nullif` is a column name ?

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct syntax

```
UPDATE systems AS C 
  INNER JOIN systems AS P 
  ON C.nullif = P.sid 
SET C.nulled = '1' 
WHERE P.status = 1
```

Comment: That did it, thank you. I'd been searching for the proper syntax and literally found nothing that would have worke.d

Comment: Oops, you beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax:

```
UPDATE `systems` AS `C`
INNER JOIN `systems` AS `P`
    ON `C`.`nullif`=`P`.`sid`
SET `C`.`nulled`='1' 
WHERE `P`.`status`=1
```